# How to load a pickle graph in django

Tags: django, celery, pickle, celery-task

I have a 500 MB networkx graph pickle object. Celery workers need this graph on each HTTP request to do some computation in background. I want to upload this graph only once in the memory on django startup.  How can I do it most efficiently?

Comment: Do you need a graph on celery side or on django? For celery worker solution check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129820/how-can-i-set-up-celery-to-call-a-custom-initialization-function-before-running

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link.  If I choose celery worker solution approach and upload the graph on worker_init() , then how can I access this graph within the @shared task function?

Comment: As in the the sample - you can use global variable.